# Floating-point equality unexpectedly working

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

We are often taught that floating-point numbers should not be compared for exact equality. However, the following function, which returns the Golden Ratio when passed any positive number, does in fact compare doubles for equality and to my surprise it seems to always work:

```
public static double f(double x) {
    double y;
    while ((y = 1 + 1 / x) != x)
        x = (x + y) / 2;
    return x;
}

@Test
void test() {
    assertEquals((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2, f(1.0));  // Passes!
}
```

I thought that maybe it works for some input arguments but not others. But even if I use JQwik's property testing, it still works!

```
@Property
void test2(@ForAll @Positive double x) {
    assertEquals((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2, f(x));  // Always passes!
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I never come across a situation where the two floating-point numbers are different by a very small amount?

Comment: What is the result of `(1+sqrt(5))/2`.... is it an `int`? And is that `int` in fact `1`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, no of course not, it's defined to be a `double` by the Java specification. Java's `Math.sqrt` always returns `double`, and every other number gets promoted to double because it takes part in an operation involving a `double`.

Comment: So `sqrt` is `Math.sqrt`? Some reason you aren't logging the values?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I wrote this test after printing out the values returned by `f(variety_of_doubles)` and seeing that it always completes (never goes into infinite loop) and always returns 1.618....

Comment: This is a great example of the sad paradox of floating-point arithmetic.  It's not perfect, meaning it does have some problems, and people always notice problems, so they loom large, and plenty of people get the — rather badly mistaken — impression that floating point arithmetic is "always inaccurate" or "terrible" or "broken".  But in fact, the IEEE-754 standard was written very carefully, and it's designed to always  give you the best possible results you can, within certain immovable constraints.  And it *does* often work very well, as your code demonstrates!

Comment: Although, with that said, it doesn't *always* work perfectly, which is why you can't always expect an exactly-equal result such as you get here.  (Also I think Java isn't exactly defined to use strict IEEE-754, so my argument breaks down a little.)

Comment: I think the bottom line is that you — perhaps accidentally — picked a good algorithm, that was guaranteed to converge, and that never ended up oscillating.  Most of the time, when you're computing a result via an infinite sequence like this, you do need to use an approximately-equal termination test, otherwise your loop may run forever if it ends up oscillating through values that are alternately a little above and a little below the "true" result.

Comment: @SteveSummit As of JEP-306 and Java 17, Java is back to using strict IEEE-754 even on Intel. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/new-features/

Comment: @SteveSummit Could you put an answer out of your comments. I would love to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... and to my surprise it seems to always work:

Not *always*.

When I tried `f(-1/1.6180339887498949)`, the `x` and `y` values oscillated between two floating point values that differed in the last few bits [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098720/floating-point-equality-unexpectedly-working/75104901#comment132526507_75098720). Thus an infinite loop.

```
x:-0.61803398874989490  y:-0.61803398874989468   // Decimal notation
x:-0x1.3c6ef372fe950p-1 y:-0x1.3c6ef372fe94ep-1  // Hex notation

x:-0.61803398874989479  y:-0.6180339887498949
x:-0x1.3c6ef372fe94fp-1 y:-0x1.3c6ef372fe950p-1

x:-0.61803398874989490  y:-0.61803398874989468
x:-0x1.3c6ef372fe950p-1 y:-0x1.3c6ef372fe94ep-1
```

`f(some_starting_x)` generally converges to render an `x`, such that `1 + 1 / x` is `x` again and so meeting the stopping condition.

Better routines can prove that if `x` is reasonably close, the `while` loop will eventually get close to the desired answer, yet even then, an oscillation, as shown above is possible.  Thus using an **iteration limit** or **close enough test** is needed.  Usually the 2 oscillation values, when close, they are *massaged* (e.g. averaged)  to form the best answer.  If not close, the looping simply failed to find a stable answer.

---

> Can anyone tell me why I never come across a situation where the two floating-point numbers are different by a very small amount?

Inadequate testing.

---

**Morale of the story**:

Do not rely on only floating point equality, except in select cases.
`f()` was not a select case and deserved additional stopping code.

---

Ref: Two `x` with math property: `x = 1 + 1/x`:

```
x1 = 1.6180339887498948482045868343656...
x2 = -0.61803398874989484820458683436564...
```

Note `x1*x2 == -1`.  `x1` is the [Golden_ratio φ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Answer (score 2):

You were just lucky, in general you don't get exact equality. Try this for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var s = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s += 0.1;
    }
    System.out.println(s == 1.0);
}
```

In your concrete example one would have to do a careful analysis to prove that your iteration always converges to the floating point number closest to phi. If sqrt also returns the closest floating point number to the exact root we would get exact equality.

Comment: I know, but the real question is "why was I lucky"? I would have expected exact results if I was dealing with numbers that can be exactly represented in floating-point binary, such as negative powers of 2. But in fact this number is an irrational number.

Comment: Yes, phi is irrational, but it turns out that phi′, which is the floating-point value (as computed by your program) that's closest to phi, is exactly equal to phi′. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit true. But I was surprised that two very different ways of calculating phi came to the exact same approximation. I guess I shouldn't have been, since there is only one possible value that is "closest to phi".